# Substitute digits with strings contained in a reference dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a`df_a` looking like:

```
df_a <- tibble::tribble(
             ~id,    ~string,
          115088, "1-3-5-13",
          678326, "1-9-13-3",
          105616, "1-3-5-13"
          )
```

Each id is associated with the `string` column, that stores strings composed by digits separated by "-".

I have a reference dataframe for which each `id_string` is associated with a string of text.

```
id <- tibble::tribble(
        ~name, ~id_string,
        "aaa",          1,
        "bbb",          3,
        "ccc",          5,
        "ddd",         13,
        "eee",          9,
        "fff",          8,
        "ggg",          6
        )
```

I would like to substitute the digits in the `string` column in `df_a` with the text stored in the reference dataframe `id`.

the result should be:

```
df_output <- tibble::tribble(
                  ~id,            ~string,
               115088,  "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd",
               678326, "aaa-eee-ddd- bbb",
               105616,  "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd"
               )
```

Comment: do the digit/dash combinations in column `string` have a consistent length (each row has same number of digits and dashes)?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you got a pretty nasty one right here, this is the type of thing i would write a dedicated c++ method and call it from R because as I see it, it has asymetries.

I wrote an iterative loop for you- it might work -Im not sure, but even if it does and your data is over 200K rows it will become a problem and might take a long time to finish.

```
temp = strsplit(df_a$string, "-") %>% lapply(function(x) as.numeric(x))
temp.List = list()
actual.List = list()

for(i in 1:length(temp)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(id)){
    if(temp[[i]] %in% id$id_string[j]){
      temp.List[j] = id$name[j]
    }else{
      temp.List[j] = NULL
    }
  }
  actual.List[[i]]= temp.List %>% unlist %>% paste(sep ='-')
}

desired.Output = cbind(df_a$id,actual.List %>% unlist)
#cleanup
rm(temp,temp.List,actual.List)
```